# Lambda Function Elementwise in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

This is a combination of the following previous questions: [Apply function to all Eigen matrix element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33786662/apply-function-to-all-eigen-matrix-element) and [Set coefficients of an Eigen::Matrix according an arbitrary distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11024820/set-coefficients-of-an-eigenmatrix-according-an-arbitrary-distribution). Basically I'm trying to generate an Eigen matrix with its coefficients sampled from a Gaussian distribution.

Here is my code to do this(static class method) which returns a rather cryptic error message:

```
matrix_eig EigenUtil::GaussianNoise(size_t rows, size_t cols,
                                    float mean, float std) {
  matrix_eig m(rows, cols);
  std::mt19937 rng;
  std::normal_distribution<float> nd(mean, std);
  auto sampler = [&]() { return nd(rng); };
  return matrix_eig::Zero(rows, cols).unaryExpr(sampler);
}
```

Which returns the the error:
error:

```
no type named 'type' in 'std::__1::result_of<(lambda at eigen_util.cpp:101:18) (const float &)>'
  typedef typename std::result_of<T>::type type1;
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a unary function, it looks like a nullary one. `std::result_of` is undefined if you can't call the given function with the given arguments. Try `[&](float /*unused*/)` perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As o11c noticed, this is indeed a nullary-expression, and there is almost the exact same example in the [doc](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a997ef3960458fb5dedb8f7f78b068a9b). I copied it for convenience:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace Eigen;
int main() {
  std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::poisson_distribution<int> distribution(4.1);
  auto poisson = [&] () {return distribution(generator);};
  RowVectorXi v = RowVectorXi::NullaryExpr(10, poisson );
  std::cout << v << "\n";
}
```

Comment: While this works correctly on my Mac, it throws an error on Ubuntu 16.04 with `g++ -std=c++11`. 
/usr/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/CoreEvaluators.h:348:27: error: no match for call to ‘(const main()::<lambda()>) (Eigen::Index&)’
     return m_functor(index);
                           ^
abc.cpp:8:23: note: candidate: main()::<lambda()>
   auto poisson = [&] () {return distribution(generator);};
                       ^
abc.cpp:8:23: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided

Comment: You need Eigen 3.3.x.